# My Tic-Tac-Toe algorithm to check for victory is not working

Tags: python, tic-tac-toe

I am trying to make a simple tic-tac-toe game. Most of it seems to be working, but drawing certain moves gives you instant victory (even without combining 3 fields) and I cannot figure out why. If you (or the computer) plays the fields 3, 6, 7, 8 or 9, you win. I guess I made a mistake in the part where I define the rules for winning (the function in my code is called victory_for). I know there are lots of tic-tac-toe codes I could use, but I want to learn something out of this as I am just beginning with Python.

This is how my starting board looks (computer always plays first with an X in the middle):

```
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   1   |   2   |   3   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   4   |   X   |   6   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
|       |       |       |
|   7   |   8   |   9   |
|       |       |       |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

This is the code I wrote. I put a # comment where I think the error lies.

```
#Computer plays with X, human plays with O.

#I need random numbers for the computer to play its turns
from random import randrange

#This is how the board looks at the beginning, assuming computer played first with an X in the middle
board = [[1, 2, 3], [4, "X", 6], [7, 8, 9]]

#Shows the current state of the board
def display_board(board):
  print(
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[0][0],"  |  ",board[0][1],"  |  ",board[0][2],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[1][0],"  |  ",board[1][1],"  |  ",board[1][2],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n|  ",board[2][0],"  |  ",board[2][1],"  |  ",board[2][2],"  |",
      "\n|       |       |       |",
      "\n+-------+-------+-------+"
      )

#Makes a list of free fields out of which the human and the computer can draw their turns
def make_list_of_free_fields(board):
  list_of_free_fields = []
  for field in range(1,10):
    for row in range(3):
      if field in board[row]:
        list_of_free_fields.append(field)
  return(list_of_free_fields)

#This is how the human enters its move
def enter_move(board):
  while True:
    user_input = int(input("Choose a field:"))
    if user_input in make_list_of_free_fields(board):
      break
    print("You must choose one of the free fields on the board by typing 1-9")
  row = (user_input - 1) // 3
  column = (user_input - 1) - row * 3
  board[row][column] = "O"

#I think this is where the error lies. It is supposed to check if the current player (defined by the sign) won.
def victory_for(board, sign):
  if (board[0][0] and board[0][1] and board[0][2] == sign or 
      board[1][0] and board[1][1] and board[1][2] == sign or 
      board[2][0] and board[2][1] and board[2][2] == sign or 
      board[0][0] and board[1][0] and board[2][0] == sign or 
      board[0][1] and board[1][1] and board[2][1] == sign or 
      board[0][2] and board[1][2] and board[2][2] == sign or 
      board[0][0] and board[1][1] and board[2][2] == sign or 
      board[0][2] and board[1][1] and board[2][0] == sign):
    return True
  else:
    return False

#This is how the computer plays its turn
def draw_move(board):
  while True:
    comp_input = randrange(10)
    if comp_input in make_list_of_free_fields(board):
      break
  row = (comp_input - 1) // 3
  column = (comp_input - 1) - row * 3
  board[row][column] = "X"


#This part is just supposed to connect everything and loop the game until someone wins.
print(
    "Welcome to Tic-Tac-Toe by me!",
    "\nPut Os on the field by choosing field numbers (1-9)",
    "\nComputer plays first by placing an X"
    )

display_board(board)

while True:
  enter_move(board)
  display_board(board)
  if victory_for(board, "O") == True:
    print("You won!")
    break
  draw_move(board)
  display_board(board)
  if victory_for(board, "X") == True:
    print("You lost!")
    break
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does "a == x or y or z" always evaluate to True? How can I compare "a" to all of those?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20002503/why-does-a-x-or-y-or-z-always-evaluate-to-true-how-can-i-compare-a-to-al)

Comment: You must compare each "board[...][...]" with "sign", not only the last in each line.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value